# rand() giving sequential numbers even when seeded on my Mac

Tags: c++, macos, random

This just started happening recently. I noticed one of my programs wasn't giving random numbers, so I made a quick simple random number program to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL))
  std::cout << rand() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Even when seeded, it keeps giving the same random number, just incremented a bit after each call. Here's a few of the numbers after running the program a few times:
874692194, 874709001, 874725808, 874742615.

I put this program on one of my Linux machines just to be sure, and as expected, it produced random numbers correctly.

So why is my Mac not producing random numbers? I already tried restarting my computer, and the problem persisted.

Before anyone says "Why not use C++'s random library?", we aren't allowed to use C++11 features in this Computing class, so that's not a solution.

Comment: Why do you think those numbers aren't (pseudo-)random? `time(NULL)` changes once per second.

Comment: @molbdnilo That's basically impossible. Even then, why is rand() generating terrible random numbers?

Comment: It's not generating terrible numbers--you're only letting it generate one number, and there's no such thing as "one random number" from a PRNG.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that still doesn't answer my question. Even if I only generate one number, it shouldn't be so close to the number generated last time.

Comment: You should not use `rand()` any way. see this https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Yes it should, because you're likely giving it the same seed since time probably only updates once a second. If you need different random numbers in different runs of the program, then you need to find some way to seed the RNG outside your program. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @CroCo I understand that you shouldn't use rand(), but it's in the spec for the assignment and I want to know why it's not working anyway

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The fact that time() has a resolution of one second is irrelevant; if that was the issue then the numbers would be the same, but they're not. I made sure to wait a second between each run anyway.

Comment: Still, if you're writing a program that only uses one random number, a PRNG--especially the standard built-in one--is probably not the best method. Better to use something like /dev/random.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The actual assignment calls random multiple times; I just noticed that the first time rand() is called in each run of the program, the number wasn't really random, or even pseudo-random. So I made this small test program to check it.

Comment: I think rand() do not guarantee randomness between executions, only between calls of rand() within the same program. ...could be wrong though....i never assumed it was safe between executions...because its state is only per-process anyways...

Comment: Yes, a PRNG is meant to produce a stream of numbers that are statistically random when analyzed as a whole. The first of these will be nothing more than a hash function of the seed--many PRNGs have a particularly bad hash function here.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza It generates random numbers between executions in Linux, just not in OSX. This wasn't happening a few days ago.

Comment: You might improve it by seeding with something like the low bits of an MD5 hash of the time plus the PID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple PRNG like rand() is designed to produce a sequence of numbers that, when analyzed as a sequence, are randomly and uniformly distributed.

If you only produce one number from a PRNG after seeding it, that first number is really just a hash of the seed, and many PRNGs have really bad seed-hashing functions.

You could improve the seed by making it, say, an MD5 hash of the time plus the process ID (and some other bits of entropy you might have lying around). But then, you could just use that as your single random number and don't really need the PRNG at all.

Comment: So then I assume that OSX's rand() (clang) produces the first random number as a hash of the seed, while Linux's rand() (gcc) does not? Because this behavior does not appear on Linux.

Comment: No, they both do, as do all PRNGs. Just different hash functions, some better than others.